# what is a better way to find a pattern in a string?

Tags: javascript, string, function

Here is what I did as a kind of practice to find patterns of different length in a given string. how can I improve it? what are the problems? it is just a question of optimization.

```
function find(pattern,str) {
   var  arr = [];
   for (i= 0;i<str.length;i++) {
      if(pattern== str.slice(i,pattern.length+i)) {
       arr.push([i,pattern.length-1+i]);
     };
  };
   if(!arr.length) { return false;} else { return arr;};
};


find('abfd','abfdffdabfdfaffab');
```

Comment: Probably a question more suitable for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ --- But I don't see any issues with this code? Looks fine to me.

Comment: Is there a reason, not to use `String.prototype.match` or `String.prototype.search` ?

Comment: alert('ajajahahagagagttss'.indexOf('jahaha') >-1)

Comment: Use `indexOf` repeatedly. (You can pass a second argument to `indexOf` that specifies where to start.)

Comment: it is every thing from scratch. I didn't want to use built-in methods

Comment: If it's all from scratch then the answer is `regex`

Comment: Also you need to put that information in your question otherwise people won't understand why your not using `indexOf` since it's so useful.

Answer (score 1):

The indexOf() method returns the position of searched pattern, -1 if pattern not found:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to locate where in the string a specifed value occurs.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function find(pattern,str) {
   var pos = str.indexOf(pattern);
   return pos === -1 ? false : [pos, pos + pattern.length-1];
}
function myFunction() {
    var pos = find('dabfd', 'abfdffdabfdfaffab');      
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 'found: ' + pos;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it is not the same, it just returns true or false. My code returns the beginning and ending index in an array and false if it is not found

Comment: corrected an answer to match the question: now it return beginning and ending index

Comment: it's nice yet it just shows the index of one found pattern, if we have two cases it doesn't show, however it is not difficult to implement it in the code. the differences are ternary operation and indexOf.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are doing str.length*(slice+compare*pattern.length), which is really inefficient if you have too many misses along the string.

Some improvements over this code can be:

- Removing slice function (assuming it is expensive and you don't need it for every step).
- Looking for the first char of the pattern in the string, then comparing the rest char by char, only after the previous char is found.
- The pattern length is already same for all occurrences of the pattern in the string, so instead of returning tuples of `[(i, i+length)]` in var, you can just return the occurrences `[i]`. (Since the caller already knows pattern.length).
- Or better, you can implement the [KMP algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm) which has complexity O(n+k).

Comment: can you do it in code plz.